# TF 2.0 conversion with graph transform in API

Tags: tensorflow

I have TF scripts, which were written in 1.1* and when converting to 2.0, I receive a: 
    No module named 'tensorflow.tools.graph_transforms'

I have installed TF 2.0 by pip but have also compiled it with --config=v2.

Any suggestion on how to resolve it?

Comment: This is being tracked in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30746